# How can redisTemplate use both JdkSerializationRedisSerializer and GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer?

Tags: java

ObjectNode & ArrayNode use GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer,
the others use JdkSerializationRedisSerializer. I can't find any effective way.

Comment: Why do you need both? Its better to store objects in a uniform way.

Comment: JdkSerializationRedisSerializer can not serialize the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode which don't implement Serializable.However,the speed of GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.serialize is slower,and the result of GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.serialize is bigger.

Comment: Thats because you try to use Jackson's ORM, which is obviously tied to Jackson's serializer. If you want generic serializer, use generic ORM.

Comment: OK,Tks.Its better to store objects in a uniform way.